# Creating a disease severity score/index

Tags: model, scales, validation

I am trying to design a numerical scale which would describe the severity of a certain disease (in this particular case anaphylaxis). I have a set of clinical symptoms and a database of patients who had anaphylaxis and had their symptoms described.

I would like to come up with a numerical value for each patient resembling the severity of their anaphylactic event.

I could assign numbers to symptoms according to their severity but this would be highly subjective (for example rash 1 point, cardiac arrest 20 points)

My question is the following: How may I validate if this what I have designed is good or  bad? How could I compare two models of this index? Are there any tools or methods that could help me with this subject ? Is there a manual or a book I could read?

By severity I mean the impact the anaphylactic event has on a patient's health. If the patient dies then the severity is the greatest.
If it is only a mild reaction like a rash/cough/rhinitis/ then the index should be low.

Comment: In addition to having data about the symptoms exhibited, do you have any data about the actual severity?  If not, then precisely what is "severity" supposed to mean?  How is this determination or score intended to be used?

Comment: There has been previous research in this field. Authors described severity on a four degree scale. The sensitivity of this scale is too low for me. This is why I would like to design my own scale. Severity issue is added in the edited question.

Comment: I think it is crucial to explain *how* the severity scale will be used.  You need to be concerned about two kinds of error: (1) underestimating severity, which (depending on the use and circumstances) could lead to foreseeable types of harm; and (2) overestimating severity, which could lead to unnecessary treatment, etc. By articulating the proposed use you can begin to explore (1) and (2), which will be essential guides towards developing your own score.

Comment: I don't think that I have to worry about the second point in this particular example as we can not foresee anaphylaxis. It can only be described after it has already happened. The proposed use would be to descibe factors which could exacerbate anaphylaxis.

Comment: If you don't have to worry about the second part, then the optimal score is to give every patient the highest possible severity.

Comment: Ok, but I am liberally assigning POINTS to SYMPTOMS, something very unquantifiable. I can't say for sure that having a cardiac arrest is 20x more bad than having a rash... How could I validate that the scores that I assign to symptoms are resembling the severity?

Comment: Your comments are starting to reveal your *real* purpose, because it now appears you are thinking of your scores as reflecting some measure of "badness."  It truly is essential for you to enhance your question to articulate your purposes and the intended meaning of this score, for otherwise the answers you are likely to get will range from speculative to downright misleading, through no fault of the respondents.

Comment: I would gladly do that If I had the skills :) But TRYING to articulate the purpose of this question: YES this scale intends to have both measures: badness and goodness... so your second comment was appropriate. How can I explain it better? What would You like o know more?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to test the association between this severity score and various factors. You may want to maximize the test power, but it depends on the (unknown) relations between your factors and the various clinical variables you want to aggregate.

I would suggest to use your data to build a score with maximal variance, picking positive weights $w_i > 0$ with $\sum_i w_i^2 = 1$ maximizing $\sum_i w_i x_i$ where the $x_i$ are the clinical variables. Before going further in this direction I am curious to get @whuber opinion on this suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method described in this [blog post](http://exploringpossibilityspace.blogspot.com/2014/02/thomas-scoring-system.html) seems well suited to your needs.  You are seeking a "severity index" which is equivalent to the "performance index" in the blog post.

There are two design decisions associated with your problem. First, what is your set of "performance hypotheses"?  i.e. How does the evidence from each of the symptoms relate to possible values in the performance index?

The second design decision relates to the scaling and resolution for index of severity.  An interval scaled index presumes that the difference between a 2 and a 4 is the same as the difference between a 4 and a 6 (on a 10 point scale).  You also need to test the limits of your scale and the regions near each extreme.

In other words, you need to both calibrate your scale and also support the claim that there is a meaningful and equal difference between successive values on the scale.  This implies that you should not use a scale whose resolution is not supported by meaningful differences.  In simple language, don't pick a 1 to 100 scale if you can only meaningfully differentiate 5 levels or states.

You asked the question: "How may I validate if this what I have designed is good or bad? How could I compare two models of this index?"

There are two ways to test your models -- 1) internal validity and 2) external validity.  Internal validity tests are those that look for consistency between rules, and consistency between definitions and outcomes.  These are basically 'bugs'.  External validity tests look for consistency between model results and out-of-band results, starting from the same inputs.

Given your situation, I'd say that external validity tests will be most important.  Essentially, for each performance hypothesis you define, you should look for one or more external (out-of-band) tests for that hypothesis.

For example, you might have some symptoms that are very common across outcomes, and thus not very informative regarding the severity index.  Likewise, you might have some symptoms that are rare and mostly associated with specific levels of severity, but also might be noisy (i.e. have high error rate, or high uncertainty).  You should look for external tests for these hypotheses from the existing body of research.